# Python - working with uneven columns in rows

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I am working with a data with thousands of rows but I have uneven columns as shown below:

```
AB  12   43   54

DM  33   41   45   56   33   77  88

MO  88   55   66   32   34 

KL  10   90   87   47   23  48  56  12
```

First, I want to read the data in list or array and then find out the length of longest row.
Then, I will add zeros to the short rows to equal them to the longest one, so that I can iterate them as a 2D array.

I have tried a couple of other similar questions, but could not work out the problem.

I believe there is a way in Python to do this. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: How would you like to actually use the data (the "2D array")? I suspect a heterogeneous 2D array is not the right data structure for this problem. If all you need is the longest row then you don't need numpy at all.

Comment: I am thinking to add zeros at end of the short rows to equal them to the longest one. Then, I can index the whole data easily.

Comment: is you data list of list? or is it external file? If you need the longest from list of lists you could use list comperehension and find it easily.

Comment: It is in a text file. I need to read the file first and then to find out the longest  row. I have edited my question above. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any easier way to figure out the maximum row length but to do one pass and to find it. Then, we build the 2D array in a second pass. Something like:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

data = '''AB 12 43 54
DM 33 41 45 56 33 77 88
MO 88 55 66 32 34
KL 10 90 87 47 23 48 56 12'''

max_row_len = max(len(line.split()) for line in data.splitlines())

def padded_lines():
    for uneven_line in data.splitlines():
        line = uneven_line.split()
        line += ['0']*(max_row_len - len(line))
        yield line

# I will get back to the line below shortly, it unnecessarily creates the array
# twice in memory:
array = np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(padded_lines())), np.dtype(object))

array.shape = (-1, max_row_len)

print(array)
```

This prints:

```
[['AB' '12' '43' '54' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['DM' '33' '41' '45' '56' '33' '77' '88' '0']
 ['MO' '88' '55' '66' '32' '34' '0' '0' '0']
 ['KL' '10' '90' '87' '47' '23' '48' '56' '12']]
```

The above code is inefficient in the sense that it creates the array twice in memory. I will get back to it; I think I can fix that.

However, **numpy arrays are supposed to be homogeneous**. You want to put strings (the first column) and integers (all the other columns) in the same 2D array. **I still think you are on the wrong track** here and should rethink the problem and pick another data structure or organize your data differently. I cannot help you with that since I don't know how you want to use the data.

(I will get back to the array created twice issue shortly.)

---

As promised, here is the solution to the efficiency issues. Note that my concerns were about memory consumption.

```
    def main():

        with open('/tmp/input.txt') as f:
            max_row_len = max(len(line.split()) for line in f)

        with open('/tmp/input.txt') as f:
            str_len_max = len(max(chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f), key=len))

        def padded_lines():
            with open('/tmp/input.txt') as f:
                for uneven_line in f:
                    line = uneven_line.split()
                    line += ['0']*(max_row_len - len(line))
                    yield line

        fmt = '|S%d' % str_len_max
        array = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(padded_lines()), np.dtype(fmt))
```

This code could be made nicer but I will leave that up to you.

The memory consumption, measured with `memory_profiler` on a randomly generated input file with 1000000 lines and uniformly distributed row lengths between 1 and 20:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     5   23.727 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     6                             def main():
     7                                 
     8   23.727 MiB    0.000 MiB       with open('/tmp/input.txt') as f:
     9   23.727 MiB    0.000 MiB           max_row_len = max(len(line.split()) for line in f)
    10                                     
    11   23.727 MiB    0.000 MiB       with open('/tmp/input.txt') as f:
    12   23.727 MiB    0.000 MiB           str_len_max = len(max(chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f), key=len))
    13                                 
    14   23.727 MiB    0.000 MiB       def padded_lines():
    15                                     with open('/tmp/input.txt') as f:
    16   62.000 MiB   38.273 MiB               for uneven_line in f:
    17                                             line = uneven_line.split()
    18                                             line += ['0']*(max_row_len - len(line))
    19                                             yield line
    20                                 
    21   23.727 MiB  -38.273 MiB       fmt = '|S%d' % str_len_max
    22                                 array = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(padded_lines()), np.dtype(fmt))
    23   62.004 MiB   38.277 MiB       array.shape = (-1, max_row_len)
```

With the code eumiro's answer, and with the same input file:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     5   23.719 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     6                             def main():
     7   23.719 MiB    0.000 MiB       with open('/tmp/input.txt') as f:
     8  638.207 MiB  614.488 MiB           arr = np.array(list(it.izip_longest(*[line.split() for line in f], fillvalue='0'))).T
```

Comparing the memory consumption increments: **My updated code consumes 16 times less memory than eumiro's** (614.488/38.273 is approx. 16).

As for speed: My updated code runs for this input for 3.321s, eumiro's code runs for 5.687s, that is, **mine is 1.7x faster** on my machine. (Your mileage may vary.)

If efficiency is your primary concern (as suggested by your comment *"Hi eumiro, I suppose this is more efficient."* and then changing the accepted answer), then I am afraid you accepted the less efficient solution.

**Don't get my wrong, eumiro's code is really concise, and I certainly learned a lot from it.** If efficiency is not my primary concern, I would go with eumiro's solution too.

Comment: Hi Ali, your code has worked excellent. This is all what I wanted. Thank you very much. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: @user30337 Please check my updated answer. My solution consumes 16x less memory and is 1.7x faster than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: thank you once again. I have little understanding about the speed. However, I am grateful to both of you for your kind helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.izip_longest` which does the finding for the longest line for you:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    arr = np.array(list(it.izip_longest(*[line.split() for line in f], fillvalue='0'))).T
```

`arr` is now:

```
array([['a', '1', '2', '0'],
       ['b', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['c', '6', '0', '0']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: Hi eumiro, I suppose this is more efficient. Thank you very much. I have upvoted your answer.